# Appendix equation number: remove space after dot

Tags: spacing, equations, appendix

In an appendix setting, for equation numbers I consistently get, e.g., (A. 1) as opposed to (A.1). The space vanishes once the number counter hits 10, e.g. (A.10). How do I remove that added space following the dot?

Here is a working latex example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{{\thesection}.
\arabic{equation}} \appendix

\section{Appendix}

\begin{equation}
    a=b.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Once compiled, I get[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Apart from the spurious whitespace issue, your approach doesn't work well if there's more than one appendix section in the document. E.g., if there are two appendices, "numbered" A and B, say, with three equations each, the equations in appendix B will be numbered as B.4, B.5, and B.6, not B.1, B.2, and B.3.

Comment: I was running into that. I solved it by adding before each new (appendix) section:   \setcounter{equation}{0} \renewcommand{\theequation}{{\thesection}.% Basically, my working example was missing some components. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every white character in the main body of TeX family's code is supposed to be a space... but more than one spaces are still supposed
to be one space ... In your case you have a "return" character at the commented point in your code: (This creates the unwanted space)

See the comment please:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{{\thesection}.% Eliminate this space
\arabic{equation}} \appendix

\section{Appendix}

\begin{equation}
    a=b.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

So, eliminate it with a comment (`%`) symbol... or just remove completely the return character from there

Comment: Just answered his question @Mico ... That is just about the space... Nothing more... Of course you are right bhut this is just a MWE... I don't even know if there are other sections or a real appendix there etc...

Comment: I'd go for `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}` .

Comment: koleygr: You're right and it worked. Thanks so much! Years of doing tex, and stilling learning ;)

Comment: Thanks @JBH ... There are other (possibly more) useful answers too here and you may select one of them... No problem for me... In any case you can learn some things from the other answers too...

Answer (score 2):

I'd replace the code block

```
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{{\thesection}.
\arabic{equation}} \appendix
```

with

```
\appendix
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
```

Why? Because your approach does not work correctly if the document contains more than one appendix section. The flaw in your setup is that it requires running `\setcounter{equation}{0}` not just once, but at the start of each appendix section.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\appendix
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\section{Supplemental material}
\begin{equation} a=b \end{equation}

\section{Proofs and sundry material}
\begin{equation} c=d \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my case "\counterwithin" was not compilable. As someone else above intuited, though, there was a return character adding the space. Thanks though.

Comment: @JBH - How old is your TeX distribution, and when was it last updated? The reason I asked is that the `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout` macros, which were part of a standalone external package, were folded into the LaTeX kernel about 3 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that very simply with the `\counterwithin` command, which is now in the latex kernel, and the `apptools` package  if only the appendix equations have to be numbered per section;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apptools}
\AtAppendix{\counterwithin{equation}{section}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\appendix
\section{Appendix}

\begin{equation}
    a=b.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]